# Xcode Build OK but Archive fails with library not found for -load_all

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, compiler-errors

I'm using webtrends which require a -load_all flag, app builds ok but wont archive

I read all the messages relating and non seem to help

```
Ld "/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PwC_UK-dsueulkkaowyeycupeqjbvsziicn/ArchiveIntermediates/Data Collection Sample/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PwC UK.build/Release-iphoneos/PwC UK.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PwC UK" normal armv6
    cd "/Users/julian/Documents/Flat Earth/PwC [-] iPhone/PwC-UK-120206"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk "-L/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PwC_UK-dsueulkkaowyeycupeqjbvsziicn/ArchiveIntermediates/Data Collection Sample/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos" "-F/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PwC_UK-dsueulkkaowyeycupeqjbvsziicn/ArchiveIntermediates/Data Collection Sample/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos" "-F/Users/julian/Documents/Flat Earth/PwC [-] iPhone/PwC-UK-120206" "-F/Users/julian/Documents/Flat Earth/PwC [-] iPhone/PwC-UK-120206/.." "-F/Users/julian/Documents/Flat Earth/PwC [-] iPhone/PwC-UK-120206/Webtrends.framework" -filelist "/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PwC_UK-dsueulkkaowyeycupeqjbvsziicn/ArchiveIntermediates/Data Collection Sample/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PwC UK.build/Release-iphoneos/PwC UK.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PwC UK.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -licucore -ObjC -load_all -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Webtrends -framework CFNetwork -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework MessageUI -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework MapKit -o "/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PwC_UK-dsueulkkaowyeycupeqjbvsziicn/ArchiveIntermediates/Data Collection Sample/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PwC UK.build/Release-iphoneos/PwC UK.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PwC UK"

ld: library not found for -load_all
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

My framework search paths are

```
$(inherited)
"$(SRCROOT)"
"$(SRCROOT)/.."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need the **-all_load** flag not **-load_all**